# ASP.NET Core- ViewBag, ViewData, TempData all empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 project. I was trying to redirect from a page to another using a controller. In the controller, I am receiving the URL parameters. I then want to send them to the view.

```
public IActionResult Index(string id, string name)
{
    // For use with ViewData and ViewBag
    // ClassName newName = new ClassName (name, id);
    TempData["Message"] = newName.name;
    return View();
}
```

Then, in my view:

```
<h4>Welcome back to @TempData["Message"]!</h4>
```

However, it's empty. In my controller, I am receiving the values for id and name correctly.

:( What am I doing wrong?

I have already tried `ViewData` and `ViewBag` - they also send empty strings.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: Purely based on the code you're showing, uncomment the line above the TempData line. If you want to eliminate the issue of you Index ActionMethod actually receiving the parameters id and name, try out TempData["Message"] = "Your Own Name"; in order to pinpoint the issue at hand.

Comment: "redirect from a page to another using a controller" Is the another page is `Index.cshtml` ? If so, you can try `ViewBag.Message =name;` and in the view:`<h4>Welcome back to @ViewBag.Message!</h4>`

Comment: Is your problem solved?  Could you build a small demo and share it via gihub so that we can test and help you ?

Answer (score 0):

The `TempData` value is only stored for a single HTTP request and is automatically cleared after that request.

If you are trying to pass data between two different actions in the same controller, you can use the `TempData` dictionary to store data that will be available for the next request:

```
public IActionResult Index(string id, string name)
{
    TempData["Message"] = $"Hello, {name} ({id})!";
    return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
}

public IActionResult Welcome()
{
    string message = TempData["Message"].ToString() "Welcome back!";
    return View("Welcome", message);
}
```

In your view, you can then display the message by using `@Model` or `@ViewData["Message"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `ViewData` or `ViewBag`. Please read [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pass-data).

`TempData` is not meant to send data to the view, but to keep state in between requests. Again: [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#tempdata).